# How to resolve when npm start gives Windows_NT and npm ERR Code ELIFECYCLE error?

Tags: node.js, node-modules

[image]

I have tried all the option by clearing cache, remove node_modules folder, re-install dependencies

Also install 'has' module separately

But not sure how to resolve this.